# redis cluster redirecting to another server and giving authentication error

Tags: redis-cluster

I have configured redis cluster with 3 master and 3 slaves on three different servers each server consists of master and slave. I have set same password to all 3 masters. While storing a value through redis-cli, it redirects to another server in the cluster and failing as auth error.

Can anyone tell me whether I can put password in redis cluster or not and how to overcome the above problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Try to post some logs error and your configuration file.

Comment: To do it on a running instance, use redis-cli and type:

config set masterauth <password>
To set it permanently, add this to your config file:

masterauth <password>